# How can I update the attributeMappings for RKObjectMapping

Tags: core-data, restkit

Because I have the Core Data objects same as the domain objects coming from the server I am using the following code to automatically setup the mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:entityClassName inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

// Get the list of attributes
NSEntityDescription* entityInfo = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityClassName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[[entityInfo attributesByName] allKeys]];
```

Later, because there is one attribute which is specific I need to update the     mapping.attributeMappings array. But I can not remove/clear the old array as it is read only. Is there any official way how to update the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would usually create a new mapping (and usually a different response descriptor such that you could switch between them without changing the configuration of the object manager).

Technically, you could subclass `RKObjectMapping`, or add a category to it, and modify `mutablePropertyMappings` to achieve your goal.